# Hello World! I am stuck on a piece of code for the HTML header for a webpage. Seemingly every piece of code I've tried doesn't work. Sharing extract

Tags: html, css, image, alignment

Here's the piece of code that I'm stuck on:-

`<div class="header">`
`<div class="motto-text" align="left">`
       `<p> &emsp; Idrk what to put here<p>&emsp; &emsp; And Cooler stuff</p></p>                 <div class="image-logo">`                    
`<img src="Cream-Logo.png" height="150px" width="150px" alt="Website Logo">`             
`</div>`          
`</div>`          
`</div>`          
`</div>`

CSS:-

`body {`     
`margin: 0px;`     
`background: #ededed;`   
`}   .header` 
`{     background: #eccbacff;`     
`margin-top: 20px;`     
`margin-bottom: 20px;`     
`width: 100vw;`   
`}   .motto-text` 
`{     font-family: 'Caveat';`     
`font-size: 30px;`     
`color: #ededed;`     
`padding-top: 30px;`     
`padding-bottom: 30px;`     
`padding-right: 0px;`    
`margin-right: 0px;`      
`}   p` 
`{     margin: 0;`   
`}   .image-logo {`
    `display: flex;`    
`align-items:center;`     
`justify-content: center;`    
`}`

I tried multiple approaches using `display: flex;` and others. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Your HTML is malformed. A `<p>` element cannot contain another `<p>` element, and there is one excessive closing `</div>` tag.

Comment: Edit and add what are you trying to achieve with this code. may be a reference image will be helpful

Comment: Putting your code through a validator might be helpful. And if when you have 'legal' code you still have a problem, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to get help with how to put code into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try This types of code changes might be working for you.

Here is HTML

```
<div class="header">
<div class="motto-text" align="left">
    <p> &emsp; Idrk what to put here</p>
    <p>&emsp; &emsp; And Cooler stuff</p>
    <div class="image-logo">                    
        <img src="Cream-Logo.png" height="150px" width="150px" alt="Website Logo">             
    </div>          
</div>
```

Here is CSS

```
body {     
    margin: 0px;     
    background: #ededed;   
}
.header{     
    background: #eccbacff;     
    margin-top: 20px;     
    margin-bottom: 20px;     
    width: 100vw;   
}
.motto-text{     
    font-family: 'Caveat';
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #ededed;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 100%;   
}
p{     
    margin: 0;   
}
.image-logo {
    display: flex;    
    align-items:center;     
    justify-content: center;    
}
```

This works well for you.